# How does this recursive function with two different return types work?

Tags: python, recursion

This function below finds the instructions to get to a specified node in a binary tree ("L"= left, "R"= right).

```
 def find(n: TreeNode, val: int, path: List[str]) -> bool:
            if n.val == val:
                return True
            if n.left and find(n.left, val, path):
                path += "L"
            elif n.right and find(n.right, val, path):
                path += "R"
            return path
```

I see that the base case returns `True` to finish the loop and also to tell preceding recursive calls that the path they're on will eventually reach the val node, but I don't understand where `return path` fits into all of this.

1. How does returning two different types of objects (`boolean` and `List[str]`) work in this recursive function?
2. Why are we returning `path` at all? Removing that line does give me the wrong answer, but I don't see anywhere where the return value is set to a variable to be used somehow.

Comment: Python doesn't have strict typing like Java or C++ by default, you can use `Class`es to make it stricter. You can have one function return more than one type as long as the caller can handle all variations. I'm assuming the caller has `if condition` that check of the two different types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A1.
The "-> bool" is called Python type hint. Python type hints are not used at runtime. <del>In fact, by the time your program runs, all the type information you’ve provided has been erased.</del> In another word, Python doesn't care type. You can learn more about Python type hint from [here](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3630372/get-started-with-python-type-hints.html).

A2-1.
The `path` variable holds the search path. When the `path` in the top level `find` is returned, you will get the full search path.

A2-2
The function in Python will returns `None` if no `return` in it. For example:

```
def foo():
    print("hello")
```

the foo returns `None`, same as foo2 below

```
def foo2():
    print("hello")
    return None
```

Comment: If all type information has been erased, then how come I'm able to [print it](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyU1TSEtP19DU0HXTiEpPz/HiksBCIpSS0qL8hRCikpTubgKijLzSjSAqvTi4xPz8vJLEksy8/OK4@M1//8HAA)?

Comment: thank you for your example, it sames that the function `foo` holds the type hint information at runtime still in Python 3.8. However, [no type information can be found in Python 3.7](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9ZNBtP//6ekpimk5edraCro2ikk5efnWHEpAEFRaklpUZ5CSFFpKhdXQVFmXokGUJVefHxiXl5@SWJJZn5ecXy85v//AA)

Comment: [Works in 3.7](https://tio.run/##LcoxDoAgDEDRvafoKIMsbg6ewp1ghEiiLSnFhNMjg3/6w8tNL6al9zNEjMyTwXnDg/leAUcStArhLjUAZEmk01DWOU/E6jUxFecMQHoyi2Jp5Wfj7BukDGF6/wA). (You picked Cython)

Comment: You are right. I think I need to update my barin. Now, i have some questions. (1) Why Python doesn't check type at runtime with the type information it holds? (2) Why it doesn't    
 raise error in [this case](https://tio.run/##LYyxDoMwDER3f4XFFA9l6daBX4lABDVSsSPbgPL1Iaq46e7p7kr1r/C7tbwXUUerBkUze@huPJNaFiaANW24iQTC14SLyO8D2KXJD2UcLtHVBnimXksK/zbRg3oaY5yZxWfvlxYjQWs3)

Comment: Sorry, don't know. I just knew that exists.

Comment: Python is dynamically typed. The language itself remains committed to not caring about static type information, but makes that information available for 3rd party tools and code that cares to examine it at runtime.